# Selenium Java Webdriver NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/config/RegistryBuilder

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium 3.7, firefox 56.0.2 and geckodriver-v0.19.0-win64 but I can't run my project:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.toolsqa.com");
```

Please help me to fix this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/http/config/RegistryBuilder

Comment: Is a maven project? could you share your pom?

Comment: no, it is not maven project

Comment: then the project have no pom

Comment: oh Sr i forgot Add the Selinium-server-standalone it worked but the browser didn't go to http://www.toolsqa.com

Comment: So, you included manually the libraries that you need? What are? only the selenium standalone server?

Comment: Ok, so you can create another question with this other issue.

Comment: yes, i included many libraries, and they are client-combined-3.7.0, byte-buddy-1.7.5, commons-codec-1.10, commons-exec-1.3, commons-logging-1.2, gson-2.8.2, guava-23.0, httpclient-4.5.3
they are in selenium-java-3.7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments I understood that you include the libraries manually. Make sure that you included all the interested libraries in your project.